# How do I insert a reference value stored in a reference table into another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my MySQL db: one that stores guides that I scrape from other sites and another one that stores Names, which are redundant, to avoid storing the same things too many times.

Guides:

- id(int)
- name(int)
- title(varchar)
- url(varchar)

Names:

- id
- Name

I have a scraper that extracts data from multiple websites and then insert the parsed data into a MySQL db: **title**, **url**. I know the Name too, but how can I compare the name I have to the ones in the reference table and insert the id into Guides.name?
How can I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert  Guides
        (name, title, url)
select  n.id
,       'TheTitleYouHave'
,       'TheUrlYouHave'
from    Names n
where   n.Name = 'TheNameYouHave'
```

or:

```
insert  Guides
        (name, title, url)
values  (
        (
        select  id
        from    Names
        where   name = 'TheNameYouHave'
        )
,       'TheTitleYouHave'
,       'TheUrlYouHave'
        )
```